# Test website performance

Tags: php, html, testing, networking, stress

I have a PHP and MySQL website using the XAMPP server.

I was just wondering is there any software, online websites etc that can test (network performance, load balance, stress tests etc) for websites that are running on a localhost (local environment)?

Thanks for any help

Comment: There's lots of tools for that, Google Pagespeed, Yahoo, GT Metrix etc, none of them work on localhost, and testing network performance and load balance on localhost makes no sense.

Comment: Other tools include Gatling, JMeter and even Apache Bench (ab).... but testing against localhost is pretty pointless when you should be testing against a production site to get any result with meaning

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't test network speed of a site on localhost, since it's going to be instant since it's local. The only thing you can test is how fast PHP can execute and there is a great extension for PHP called [php_xdebug](http://xdebug.org/). It will tell you how long each function call takes to execute.

You can view the results using tools such as [WinCacheGrind](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wincachegrind/) and view which function is taking up all your time.

For the network stuff, you need to first deploy your website and then run the tests for load balancing, stress testing, etc.

From my experience, most of the delay from websites is from PHP and not the web server (unless you are on a shared host).